# django-admin-tools 0.8 после установки и настройки выдает ошибку 404 при попитке входа в админку

Tags: django, плагин, django-admin

Установила и настроила плагин django-admin-tools 0.8 согласно документации. Версия django 1.11.4. Проект делаю через virtualenv.

Настройки в файле settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'admin_tools',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'atelierapp',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        #'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.core.context_processors.request',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

Файл urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^admin_tools/', include('admin_tools.urls')),
]
```

Но когда хочу зайти в админку, выпадает ошибка:

> 404 File not found

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

Вопрос: в чем проблема?
Спасибо за уделенное время.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло вот это

```
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
        ],
        'loaders': [
                    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                    'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
        ],
    },
```

Нашёл через гугл, кажется в "вопросах и ответах" самого инструмента django-admin-tools

PS: В urls.py комментировать строку admin нет нужды. Просто при входе в my-site.net/admin вместо стандартной админки появляется новая.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, если еще поставить 'APP_DIRS': False. Но появилась новая проблема: теперь не находит файлы в Templates. Поскольку ищет по таким путям: django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Anastasiia\Envs\.env\lib\site-packages\admin_tools\theming\templates\templates\home.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\Anastasiia\Envs\.env\lib\site-packages\admin_tools\menu\templates\templates\home.html (Source does not exist) и тд.
Как мне это исправить?

Comment: Замечательная проблема. Если учесть, что я работаю в линуксе ;). А если серьёзно:

Comment: - если забыли, надо еще добавить `STATICFILES_FINDERS=django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder` в settings.py. А  после настройки settings.py нужно запустить команды миграции `manage.py makemigrations` и `manage.py migrate`. на всякий случай я еще запускал "коллекцию статики" `manage.py collectstatic`, хотя и получил сообщение 0 переписанных файлов. Всё согласно официальной документации, туториалу. Хотя и та далеко не полная. Есть намёк на работу в Django версии 1.8, про поздние - ни слова.

Comment: PS: нажатие клавиши Enter в этом поле ввода сразу "добавляет комментарий". Который можно править раз в 5 минут, если на странице ничего не глючит (